# How to share installed plugins in IntelliJ with team

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a project I want to share with my team including IntelliJ setup. The project requires several IntelliJ plugins for convenient work. How can I share plugin setup with my team easily, so they don't need to install plugins one-by-one?

Comment: This feature request is open since 10 years now :) https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-35331

Comment: I see, that's quite sad :( Thanks for the link, I voted for the issue

Comment: Install intellij in docker. Share that using private docker hub account. When starting the containers mount the x-server on the linux laptops you're all using (note: not macs).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [Required Plugins](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2018.1/required-plugin.html?utm_medium=link&utm_source=product&utm_campaign=IU&utm_content=2018.2) setting (`Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Required Plugins`). Here you can specify plugins required for your project. When the project is opened and a required plugin is not installed, a warning will show with a link to download the plugin.

[image: Required Plugins settings dialog]